# Move QGraphicsView top left to a certain point in QGraphicsScene manually

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsView` subclass, holding a `QGraphicsScene` subclass, inside a `QWidget`.

The `QGraphicsScene` has an actual drawing rectangle with top let corner at (0,0) (so the scene really has a `QRectF(-x,-y,w,h)` of values irrelevant to the problem).

On startup, actually in the `showEvent` of the widget, I set the size of the scene to fit the custom sized rectangle. That also centers it.

What I would like, is to match the (0,0) point of the scene to the top left of the view, on start.

Unlike other questions with the same title, I actually need to move the view, not the items inside the scene.

Image 1: actual start, image 2: desired

[image: actual] [image: desired]

I am trying:

```
void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    static bool startUp = true;
    if(startUp)
    {
        QSizeF sz = m_scene->getActualSize();
        ui->graphicsView->fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, sz.width(), sz.height()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        QPointF zero = ui->graphicsView->mapFromScene(QPointF(0,0));
        ui->graphicsView->translate(-zero.x(), -zero.y()); // or positive

        startUp = false;
    }
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

note: I use the `fitInView` to get the desired zoom - and it also brings the desired rectangle in focus - but centered in the view.

I also tried

```
void GraphicsView::alignToZero()
{
    QPointF zero = this->mapFromScene(QPointF(0,0));
    this->scrollContentsBy(-zero.x(), -zero.y());
}

void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    static bool startUp = true;
    if(startUp)
    {
        QSizeF sz = m_scene->getActualSize();
        ui->graphicsView->fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, sz.width(), sz.height()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        ui->graphicsView->alignToZero();

        startUp = false;
    }
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

Still no result.

Also tried

```
void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    static bool startUp = true;
    if(startUp)
    {
        QSizeF sz = m_scene->getActualSize();
        ui->graphicsView->fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, sz.width(), sz.height()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        QPointF zero = ui->graphicsView->mapFromScene(QPointF(0,0));
        //ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
        ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(zero.x());
        ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(zero.y());

        startUp = false;
    }
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

This, with or without the alignment setting (which I think may have unwanted effects elsewhere), moves the view... too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there must be a better way... I figured out a way to get my 0's aligned by doing `fitInView` twice:

```
void MyWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    static bool startUp = true;
    if(startUp)
    {
        QSizeF sz = m_scene->getActualSize();
        // First I do a normal `fitInView` that centers the rectangle
        ui->graphicsView->fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, sz.width(), sz.height()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        // Then, knowing the shift, I fit it again adding twice the shift to the size.
        QPointF zero = ui->graphicsView->mapToScene(QPoint(0,0));
        ui->graphicsView->fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, sz.width() - 2 * zero.x(), sz.height() - 2 * zero.y()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        startUp = false;
    }
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I am struggling with trying to create a ruler on top and left as you did. I have been doing a lot of research and tried many different solutions but never reached a good result until I bumped into this question. I was wondering if you could share the code on how you created it please? Thanks if you can! :)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, to achieve desired effect you can use method

QGraphicsView::setAlignment(Qt::Alignment alignment):

```
ui->graphicsView->setAlignment( Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft );
```

Which is commented in your code.
This method with those arguments aligns view top-left, you don't have to move or fit anything.